# Redux Setting on custom created admin page

Tags: theme-development

I am using Redux Framework and I am creating a theme and I want all my theme option on my custom created page Like this

[image: Reference AVADA Theme]

but by default Redux Created a different page like this

[image: Redux deafult options page]

I am using this configuration

```
$options_name = 'wee_redux';
$options_name = apply_filters('wee_redux/options_name', $options_name);
$theme = wp_get_theme();
$args = [
    'opt_name'             => $options_name,
    'display_name'         => $theme->get( 'Name' ),
    'display_version'      => $theme->get( 'Version' ),
    'menu_type'            => 'menu',
    'allow_sub_menu'       => true,
    'menu_title'           => __( 'Theme_options' ),
    'page_title'           => __( 'Theme_options' ),
    'google_api_key'       => '',
    'google_update_weekly' => true,
    'dev_mode'             => false,
    'async_typography'     => true,
    'admin_bar'            => true,
    'admin_bar_icon'       => 'dashicons-portfolio',
    'admin_bar_priority'   => 50,
    'update_notice'        => true,
    'customizer'           => false,
    'page_permissions'     => 'manage_options',
    'use_cdn'              => true,
   ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `menu_type` to `submenu`.  ;)

Comment: I changed menu_type  to submenu and then add an extra parameter 'page_parent' => 'parent-page'   and its work for me thanks buddy